# How to remove the ":", for the FindOne of my query in SQL-Server?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

Ok, I just want to get an object from my database, so I'm using sequelize, but at query time it brings me ": 80810", so it sends me an error in the database: "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value ': 80810' to data type int. ", because the field I am trying to query is INT and as the request, I am sending the colon": ", it already changes to nvarchar, but I don't know how to remove the colon (:) in the req.params.id_alquiler in node para, that does not take it verbatim to the script when it is executed in the SQL-SERVER.

```
router.get('/rt:id_alquiler', exports.findOne = (req, res) => {
    const id_alquiler = req.params.id_alquiler;
    Rent.findByPk(id_alquiler)
    .then(data => {
        res.json(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
             message: 'Error', err
         });
     });
 })
```

What comes to the SQL-SERVER

```
SELECT [id_alquiler]
    ,[nombre_periodo]
    ,[nombre_tipo_exhibidor]
    ,[nombre_estado_alquiler]
    ,[marca]
    ,[nombre_sucursal]
    ,[fecha_ingreso_alquiler]
FROM [View_RENTS_PDTs] AS [View_RENTS_PDT]
WHERE [View_RENTS_PDT].[id_alquiler] = N':80810';
```

But if I remove the colon: in (N'80810 ';), then if you bring me the object. So how do you run it in the database, it sends me error 500, but it is only for the colon ":", which are included in the sequelize query, do you know how to remove them or how could I solve them on the database side?

Grateful with the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to replace the ':' and parse it to numeric value and then pass, something like this:

const id_alquiler = parseInt(req.params.id_alquiler.replace(':', ''));